# Why can datetime allow this decimal format but datetime2 won't?

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, type-conversion, datetime2

I just ran into an issue where my program was not able to convert a `string` to a `datetime2` value. The value was `12/17.2020`. When converting this to `datetime` it worked, but when converting it to `datetime2` it didn't. What is the reason for this? How can `12/17.2020` be valid?

Comment: SQL Server supports lots of older "irregular" functionality to preserve backward-compatibility. Datetime2 was a new datatype and MS decided to not support this (and other things as well, like using the mathematical + operator).

Answer (score 3):

`12/17.2020` is a terrible format to begin with, not just because of mixed punctuation but also because [it is ambiguous](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/16/bad-habits-to-kick-mis-handling-date-range-queries). Luckily we can tell that is `mm/dd.yyyy` but what if you showed us `12/08.2020`?

> How can 12/17.2020 be valid?

Just because it is valid in one context doesn't mean you should use it (or be mad at the newer types that "break" it). It is not valid for any good reason - this format certainly isn't listed in the [Supported Literal String Formats section of the `datetime` docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/datetime-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15).

It is valid simply because the older data types (`datetime`/`smalldatetime`) were more forgiving. They also let you use shorthand like this:

```
DECLARE @d datetime;
SET @d = 0;
SELECT @d + 1;
```

Try those with `date` or `datetime2` and you will be met with:

> Msg 206, Level 16, State 2
> Operand type clash: int is incompatible with datetime2

The why isn't really important. What you need is a workaround.

1. Ideally, you can fix your inbound format to be an unambiguous format universally understood by all date/time data types, and immune to problematic factors like regional settings, language settings, and dateformat settings:

   ```
   yyyymmdd
   ```
2. You can get around this *in some cases* using the [horribly inefficient `FORMAT` function](https://sqlperformance.com/2015/06/t-sql-queries/format-is-nice-and-all-but) or replacing first but, if you can't change the incoming format, probably your simplest answer is to just run two converts:

   ```
   SELECT CONVERT(datetime2, CONVERT(datetime, '12/17.2020'));
   ```
3. If you're just trying to blindly pass `12/17.2020` into a stored procedure parameter or insert it directly into a column from your application, you're going to be out of luck. Please see 1.